# No hyper-v daemons available in 22.04?

Tags: 22.04, backup, virtualization, hyper-v

I have been looking for quite some time for a way to download the Hyper-v Daemons in Ubuntu 22.04 server as it seems my install did not come with any. The last thing I found was a [microsoft guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/virtualization/hyper-v/manage/manage-hyper-v-integration-services) on how to enable them and such, but their command to show all the available daemons was empty- even as super user. Even using systemctl to check if any are running I just get `Unit hv-vss-daemon.service could not be found.`

I'm really at a loss as to why these weren't pre-installed, or even how to install them.

Really what I am trying to do here is back up my hyper-v machines, which is working fine for any windows VMs that I have but not working at all for ANY of our Ubuntu VMs.

Answer (score 3):

There are no standalone Hyper-V daemons for Ubuntu, you need to install the custom Hyper-V kernel from Microsoft:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-azure
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/virtualization/hyper-v/supported-ubuntu-virtual-machines-on-hyper-v

Comment: This kernel is not from Microsoft. It is developed by Canonical and the code is available on launchpad: https://code.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux-azure. It is named `linux-azure` because it is tuned to perfectly fit Microsoft Azure's environment.